# Using Primefaces menubar by keyboard

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accessibility

Is it possible to use the PrimeFaces-Menu / Menubar by just using the keyboard instead of the mouse?
I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 with JSF 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You could use p:hotkey as shown in below link

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/hotkey.jsf